# CSS transitions blocking each other

Tags: css, transition

Following example explains my problem:
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sTFT3/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7292/9388249554_18f230a0ce_z.jpg" class="image"/>
<img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2814/9389265805_1fd4040203_z.jpg"/>
<span class="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    position: relative
}
.parent .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition : max-height 1s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition : max-height 1s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition : max-height 1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition : max-height 1s linear 0s;
    transition : max-height 1s linear 0s;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition : opacity 1s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition    : opacity 1s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition     : opacity 1s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition      : opacity 1s ease-in 0s;
    transition         : opacity 1s ease-in 0s;
}

.parent:hover .text {
    max-height: 600px;
}

.parent:hover .image {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I need the animations to start together, but they are waiting for each other. Couldn't find anyone else with that kind of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They start at the same time, but because you have a max-height of `600px`'s on the top div it finishes faster. Change this to a lower value and they will animate at the same time and duration

http://jsfiddle.net/sTFT3/2/

The problem is that if you set max-height of 600 while the div is only 20 px's big, it will increase the animation drasticly because it will animate to 600px's height in 1 second instead of 20px's.